# Changing cpu from intel to amd

Tags: hard-drive, swap, cpu

I currently have two computers using ubuntu, I want to switch the hard drives of the two so the one I use more has more space. My problem is one of my computers has a intel cpu and one has a amd CPU, would I be able to successfully swap hard drives? Both use ddr2 ram and have amd graphics cards (6xxx and a 5xxx series card) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drivers for both should both should both be installed, so it should work - you may want to backup any important data first to prepare for if anything goes wrong.

Various accounts of success can be found [here on the SuperUser forum](https://superuser.com/questions/183958/upgrade-motherboard-and-cpu-without-reinstall).

I have previously had success taking a drive out of laptop and running it of a USB connector on a desktop *(probably with different processors)*, so hopefully it should work for you. One area you may need to be wary about is graphic card drivers, but most of the time it should work.

**EDIT (after a lot more experience!):** 
Yes it should work. However in the event you have installed additional drivers for included hardware (e.g. integrated GPU drivers) they may slow down the system and/or crash bootup entirely (for that specific latter issue see ***Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time*** [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/178596))