# GRUB slow with new CPU (Intel -> AMD)

Tags: drivers, grub2

I noticed that grub was really slow after I changed PC and found [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227735/grub-is-extremely-slow-1-second-per-key-input?noredirect=1#comment2095971_1227735). It sounded like the exact same thing I had and soon we figured out that we both switched PCs and both from an Intel CPU to an AMD one. Do I need to update any configs? I tried to re-install grub several times now with no luck (I also have a grub-theme which I haven't messed around yet. Could this be a problem?).

And not addressing grub at all, would I need to change anything system-wise when switching CPU? According to  [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425237/changing-cpu-from-intel-to-amd), it should be fine. Granted, it is 6 years old now soo... maybe I have to run some sort of config update? Just as a note, I haven't experienced any issues except grub being enormously slow.

Glad to add additional system information if required and looking forward to suggestions :)